# Sum in range defined by column

Tags: sql, ansi-sql

I have a table that is something like this:

| amount | status | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | A | 0 |
| 10 | B | 1 |
| 15 | B | 2 |
| 10 | C | 3 |
| 12 | D | 4 |
| 20 | A | 5 |
| 25 | B | 6 |
| 17 | C | 7 |
| 19 | D | 8 |

The amounts have no restriction (other than being a number). And status lines can have duplicates (the 'B' in the example).

What I want is to sum over everything between 'A' status. So the result should be

| sum | timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| 57 | 1 |
| 81 | 5 |

I need this for ansi-sql (Spark)

Comment: There must be more to your data than you have provided, there is nothing to provide any ordering to your data.

Comment: for sql a table is by nature unsorted, so the database can't differentiate between B in the second row and the 7th, so there is no way to write an algorithm, to sum them up

Comment: @Stu, didn't realise it matters. Added a timestamp

Comment: @IttayD, timestamp of the results are 1, 5. not 0, 5 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you will have decided about your "order" column, one possible solution:

```
with data(ord, amount, status) as (
    select 1, 10, 'A' from dual union all
    select 2, 10, 'B' from dual union all
    select 3, 15, 'B' from dual union all
    select 4, 10, 'C' from dual union all
    select 5, 12, 'D' from dual union all
    select 6, 20, 'A' from dual union all
    select 7, 25, 'B' from dual union all
    select 8, 17, 'C' from dual union all
    select 9, 19, 'D' from dual 
),
pdata as (
    select d.*, case status when 'A' then lv else last_value(lv) ignore nulls over(order by ord) end as llv
    from (
        select d.*, 
            nvl(last_value(case status when 'A' then ord end) over(partition by status order by ord
                RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
            ), case status when 'A' then ord - 1 
            end) as lv
        from data d
    ) d
)
select sum(amount) from pdata
where llv is not null
group by llv
;

sum(amount)
57
81
```

Note that replacing "when 'A' then lv else" by "when 'A' then null else" will give you the sum of rows strictly between the 2 'A' (not including the first one).

Comment: Thanks. What are p_ord and n_ord used for?

Comment: nothing: remaining stuff used during testing that I forgot to remove when posting.

Comment: Note that if using TIMESTAMP for ordering, you may get "ORA-00902" on the "RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING", then instead of selecting directly from the source table, select from a subquery where you will add "row_number() over(order by the_timestamp_column) as ord", then it will work again.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution :

```
with data(ts, amount, status) as (
    select to_timestamp('27-11-2022 12:00:00.00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF'), 10, 'A' from dual union all
    select to_timestamp('27-11-2022 12:00:00.00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF')+1/24, 10, 'B' from dual union all
    select to_timestamp('27-11-2022 12:00:00.00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF')+2/24, 15, 'B' from dual union all
    select to_timestamp('27-11-2022 12:00:00.00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF')+3/24, 10, 'C' from dual union all
    select to_timestamp('27-11-2022 12:00:00.00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF')+4/24, 12, 'D' from dual union all
    select to_timestamp('27-11-2022 12:00:00.00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF')+5/24, 20, 'A' from dual union all
    select to_timestamp('27-11-2022 12:00:00.00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF')+6/24, 25, 'B' from dual union all
    select to_timestamp('27-11-2022 12:00:00.00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF')+7/24, 17, 'C' from dual union all
    select to_timestamp('27-11-2022 12:00:00.00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF')+8/24, 19, 'D' from dual 
)
select res from (
    select 
        status, ts, sum(amount) over(partition by s) as res
    from (
        select 
            d.*, sum(flag) over(order by ts) as s
        from (select d.*, decode(status,'A',1,0) as flag from data d) d
    ) d
)
where status = 'A'
order by ts
;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another possibility, assuming table name is `Tmp`:

```sql
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS summing;
DELIMITER |
CREATE PROCEDURE summing()
    BEGIN
        DECLARE _begin INT DEFAULT NULL;
        DECLARE _end INT DEFAULT NULL;
        
        SELECT `timestamp` INTO _begin FROM Tmp WHERE status='A' ORDER BY `timestamp` LIMIT 1;
        
        IF _begin IS NOT NULL THEN
            
            SELECT `timestamp` INTO _end FROM Tmp WHERE  status='A' AND `timestamp` > _begin ORDER BY `timestamp` LIMIT 1;
            WHILE _end IS NOT NULL DO
                SELECT SUM(amount) FROM Tmp WHERE `timestamp` > _begin AND `timestamp` < _end;
                SET _begin = _end;
                SET _end = NULL;
                SELECT `timestamp` INTO _end FROM Tmp WHERE  status='A' AND `timestamp` > _begin ORDER BY `timestamp` LIMIT 1;
            END WHILE;
        END IF;
    END|
DELIMITER ;

CALL summing ();
```

I have test it on MySQL server.